# Titanium : Can i update an app use SDK 3.4.0GA without optimizing it for iPhone 6 and 6 plus?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

I would like to know, using the SDK 3.4.0G.A, if I can upload the update of my app, but without optimization it for iPhone 6 and iphone 6 plus (so the app on the iPhone 6 and iphone 6 plus is displayed as on the iphone 5) , without entering the splash screen for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus

I have already upload an update of another of my app (without optimizing the app for iPhone 6 and 6 plus), but using the SDK 3.3.0 GA , with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

No problem would be seen during submitting the app from 3.4.0 and not optimized for iPhone6 and plus as i have done myself yesterday

Thanks